# jQuery set focus out of element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to be able programmatically take focus out of element.

Is it possible to do this with jQuery?

My problem is that one element has focus by default when page is loaded.
I would like to take focus out of this element.

I have only jQuery on this form. (no angular)

Comment: __`jQuery.trigger('blur')`__

Comment: You can focus on some other element..

Comment: you see http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_events.asp

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this for your input field in document ready

```
$("#myInputID").blur();
```

Answer (score 1):

Run blur function on window ready. 
Following is the code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#target" ).blur();
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `blur()` to remove focus from an element. In the following example, as soon as you focus on the input box, blur() is called and the focus is removed.

```js
$('#id1').focus(function(){
  $(this).blur();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="id1" type = "text">
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
$(function () {

    $("#yourid").focus();
});
```